# Javascript Array to Blazor component

Tags: arrays, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

How would I get an array from a Javascript function to a blazor component? Here in the component I call the Javascript function ,initializeJs.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("initializeJs", null);
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Then I get an array from a ARCGIS service  in my JavaScript.

```
function initializeJs(){ var dataArray = results.features}
```

[image: The Array]How do I send the dataArray back to the Blazor component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            var dataArray = await JS.InvokeAsync<string[]>("initializeJs", null);
            Console.WriteLine($"{dataArray[0]}");
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
```

and in your js you can just return the `dataArray`

```
function initializeJs() {
    var dataArray = ["A", "B", "C"];
    return dataArray;
}
```